# 2D arrays with contiguous rows on the heap memory for cudaMemCpy2D()

Tags: c++, arrays, cuda

[CUDA documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory) recommends the use of `cudaMemCpy2D()` for 2D arrays (and similarly `cudaMemCpy3D()` for 3D arrays) instead of `cudaMemCpy()` for better performance as the former allocates device memory more appropriately. On the other hand, all `cudaMemCpy` functions, just like `memcpy()`, require contiguous allocation of memory.

This is all fine if I create my (host) array as, for example, `float myArray[h][w];`. However, it most likely will not work if I use something like:

```
float** myArray2 = new float*[h];
for( int i = 0 ; i < h ; i++ ){
   myArray2[i] = new float[w];
}
```

This is not a big problem except when one is trying to implement CUDA into an existing project, which is the problem I am facing. Right now, I create a temporary 1D array, copy the contents of my 2D array into it and use `cudaMemCpy()` and repeat the whole process to get the results after the kernel launch, but this does not seem an elegant/efficient way.

Is there a better way to handle this situation? Specifically, is there a way to create a genuine 2D array on the heap with contiguously allocated rows so that I can use `cudaMemCpy2D()`?

P.S: I couldn't find the answer to this question the following previous similar posts:

- [Allocate 2D array with cudaMallocPitch and copying with
  cudaMemcpy2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991667/allocate-2d-array-with-cudamallocpitch-and-copying-with-cudamemcpy2d)
- [Assigning memory for contiguous 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641509/assigning-memory-for-contiguous-2d-array)
- [Dynamic 2d Array non contiguous memory c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972951/dynamic-2d-array-non-contiguous-memory-c) (The second answer in
  this one is rather puzzling.)

Comment: It's not clear to me why your second link is not the solution.

Comment: @AnonMail, I could be wrong but in that question a container is defined (similar to std::vector). Internally it uses a 1D array to achieve contiguous allocation. Also similar to std::vector and std::map one cannot directly access elements of the container using pointers and should use iterators instead. I doubt one can copy the contents of such objects using memcpy().

Comment: @RobertCrovella, thanks for the comment. That (flattening the 2D array manually prior to HostToDevice copy) is exactly what I am doing right now in my application. I was hoping to find a way to do it differently so I can take advantage of more efficient memory allocation of cudaMemCpy2D(). Looks like this is the only way.

Comment: I was assuming you did not want to modify the host (allocation) code *at all*.  But that is not correct. Actually you are willing to modify the host code, but you want to preserve doubly-subscripted access on the host.  In that case, the answer by @DaleWilson is a great suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allocate the big array, then use pointer arithmetic to find the actual beginnings of the rows.

```
float* bigArray = new float[h * w]
float** myArray2 = new float*[h]
for( int i = 0 ; i < h ; i++ ){
   myArray2[i] = &bigArray[i * w];
}
```

Your myArray2 array of pointers gives you C/C++ style two dimensional arrays behavior, bigArray gives you the contiguous block of memory needed by CUDA.

Comment: Thanks, @Dale Wilson. Just to clarify, this way I can pass myArray2 to cudaMemCpy2D(), right?

Comment: Note that I edited my post to make the first line new float[h*w] rather than new float*[h*w].   sorry for the typo.  Now about your question:   You should probably use bigArray to pass the array to CUDA, but you could also use myArray[0].   In any case you need a pointer to the contiguous array of floats, not a pointer to the pointer to the array which is what passing myArray2 would give you.

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, I do not. Could please elaborate a bit more as to why I should not use myArray[0]?

Comment: You can use `myArray2[0]`.  In my now-deleted comment, I said you should use `bigArray` not `myArray2`.  But you can also use `myArray2[0]`, since by inspection that is identical to `bigArray`.